# As soon as the user scrolls, hide div then show when back to the top

Tags: jquery, scroll, hide, jscrollpane, show-hide

When a page is loaded I have two divs that are displayed, when the user starts to scroll, hide divs. When the user gets back to the top, show divs again. This is simple enough when using the window as the target, however I'm using jScrollPane instead and not quite sure how to target the scroll pane correctly:

```
$('.content').scroll(function() {
console.log($(this).scrollTop());
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
     {
        $('#bb-nav-next').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('#bb-nav-next').fadeIn();
     }
 });
```

A bit of code I think might be affecting the performance (this bit of code comes from: http://pastebin.com/UmyJ6zBW):

```
function setJSP( action, idx ) {

    var idx = idx === undefined ? current : idx,
        $content = $items.eq( idx ).children( 'div.content' ),
        apiJSP = $content.data( 'jsp' );

    if( action === 'init' && apiJSP === undefined ) {
        $content.jScrollPane({verticalGutter : 0, hideFocus : true });
    }
    else if( action === 'reinit' && apiJSP !== undefined ) {
        apiJSP.reinitialise();
    }
    else if( action === 'destroy' && apiJSP !== undefined ) {
        apiJSP.destroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this ? , try to log the values to track

Comment: How do I log the values?

Comment: console.log($(this).scrollTop());

Comment: Excuse my noob questions but where do I view the log? I see nothing in console?

Comment: Then you are not reaching the scroll function :)

Comment: When I see this: http://cl.ly/image/0Z1c3k2s0O2C Does it mean thats the function?

Comment: There must be a problem with my code then because it doesn't seem to work when I use the updated code (see updated question)

Comment: Make a demo on jsfiddle.net please maybe we can help more

Comment: I can't makea demo unfortunately as I can't get it working in JsFiddle. See updated question for a bit code that I think is affecting the performance

Answer (score 0):

As per underrating you want to show a DIV only and when user is at top visible area of screen. And once user scroll down the div need to invisible, for that use following method

```
$(document).on('load scroll', splDiv);
$(window).on('resize', splDiv);
var ele = $('#bb-nav-next');

function splDiv() {
if($(window).scrollTop() > window.innerHeight){
    ele.fadeOut();
}else{
    ele.fadeIn();
}
};
```

Basically on document load and scroll we associate the splDiv method with it hence when you scroll down after the your first visible area it will hide the your ‘#bb-nav-next’ element.

We do add also resize method as on tab on rotation it works also